# Linking boost::thread

Tags: c++, boost, linker, boost-thread

I'm trying to learn something with boost libraries, but I get a problem when I try to compile something that includes boost::threads.
I get an error during linking, this is the message:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost-thread
```

But it's strange because this happens only when I compile with a normal user, using root I can compile with no problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was the command you ran?  Usually you have to supply `-L[/path/to/boost]` somewhere in there so it knows where to find it.

Comment: Recent versions of boost would require to use "-lboost_thread"

Comment: This is the command I ran:
g++ -L/usr/local/boost_1_48_0/stage/lib  -lboost-thread threadBoost.cpp, but it works only from root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the lib name in boost install path (default: /usr/lib/), if it's libboost_thread.so, add -lboost_thread. Don't forget to specify the path to boost directory with -L/usr/lib/boost.
If it only work as root, check your privilege in this directory :

```
ls -la /usr/lib/ | grep boost
```

you should see your login, and rw_r_*r*_ (check you have the read permission).

If you have this permission on the directory and on the boost lib, linking with gcc can be done :

```
g++ obj.o obj2.o -L/usr/lib -lboost_thread
```

if you don't own files or don't have read permissions, log as root and add them

```
chown -R /usr/lib <your login>
chmod +r /usr/lib/lib*.so
```

Comment: I've already checked permissions but there are 0k(777), I compile with this:
g++ -L/usr/local/boost_1_48_0/stage/lib -lboost-thread threadBoost.cpp
but still I get:
cannot find -lboost-thread

Answer (score 7):

Include

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
```

Other Linker Flags

```
-lboost_system -lboost_thread-mt
```

Answer (score 0):

Add /path/to/boost to your makefile Library Include path and your error will go away.

The other option is include boost it into your LIBPATH variable